# Increase C++ regex replace performance

Tags: python, c++, regex, performance, replace

I'm a beginner C++ programmer working on a small C++ project for which I have to process a number of relatively large XML files and remove the XML tags out of them. I've succeeded doing so using the C++0x regex library. However, I'm running into some performance issues. Just reading in the files and executing the regex_replace function over its contents takes around 6 seconds on my PC. I can bring this down to 2 by adding some compiler optimization flags. Using Python, however, I can get it done it less than 100 milliseconds. Obviously, I'm doing something very inefficient in my C++ code. What can I do to speed this up a bit?

My C++ code:

```
std::regex xml_tags_regex("<[^>]*>");

for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = _files.begin(); it != 
        _files.end(); it++) {

    std::ifstream file(*it);
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    size_t size = file.tellg();

    std::string buffer(size, ' ');

    file.seekg(0);
    file.read(&buffer[0], size);

    buffer = regex_replace(buffer, xml_tags_regex, "");

    file.close();
}
```

My Python code:

```
regex = re.compile('<[^>]*>')

for filename in filenames:
    with open(filename) as f:
        content = f.read()
        content = regex.sub('', content)
```

P.S. I don't really care about processing the complete file at once. I just found that reading a file line by line, word by word or character by character slowed it down considerably.

Comment: Are you sure time spent on regex but not on file read? (Hint try to execute with regex_replace commented out). What environment do you have (compiler, OS etc)?

Comment: The file reading right now is only taking around 20-25ms. I'm using the g++ compiler on Mac OS X Mavericks.

Comment: What version is gcc? run `g++ -v`

Comment: Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0
Thread model: posix

Comment: What `-O` level are you using?

Comment: I'm using -O3 to achieve the ±2000ms

Comment: All I can think is that `regex_replace` is creating a copy of the string rather than executing in-place and that copy is taking a long time. Note that `regex_replace` returns its result _by-value_, indicating that a copy is occurring somewhere.

Comment: How big is the file ? And how fragmented is it ? Perhaps the seek is costing you performance. You should really be using stat to compute file size.

Comment: @TartanLlama If reading the file takes ~25ms, surely copying it should take *less* time. @user1219263 PLEASE use `with` for files. It's a moral thing. Not doing it is a crime ;P.

Comment: @Saish The results are from running the program on around 40 files of 300kB each. Thanks for the tip, but using stat instead of the seeks doesn't increase performance. The file I/O is only taking around 25ms as said earlier, so most of the time is spent in the regex_replace(..) function.

Comment: @Veedrac Oops, edited :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you're doing anything "wrong" per-say, the C++ regex library just isn't as fast as the python one (for this use case at this time at least). This isn't too surprising, keeping in mind the python regex code is all C/C++ under the hood as well, and has been tuned over the years to be pretty fast as that's a fairly important feature in python, so naturally it is going to be pretty fast.

But there are other options in C++ for getting things faster if you need. I've used PCRE ( http://pcre.org/ ) in the past with great results, though I'm sure there are other good ones out there these days as well.

For this case in particular however, you can also achieve what you're after without regexes, which in my quick tests yielded a 10x performance improvement. For example, the following code scans your input string copying everything to a new buffer, when it hits a `<` it starts skipping over characters until it sees the closing `>`

```
std::string buffer(size, ' ');
std::string outbuffer(size, ' ');

... read in buffer from your file

size_t outbuffer_len = 0;
for (size_t i=0; i < buffer.size(); ++i) {
    if (buffer[i] == '<') {
        while (buffer[i] != '>' && i < buffer.size()) {
            ++i;
        }
    } else {
        outbuffer[outbuffer_len] = buffer[i];
        ++outbuffer_len;
    }
}
outbuffer.resize(outbuffer_len);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! I've tried both your suggestions. PCRE is actually a lot faster than the standard REGEX library using `pcrecpp::RE("<[^>]*>").GlobalReplace("", &buffer);` which runs in about 80ms on my system (just about as fast as Python does!). The second solution that you suggested, which uses no regexes, runs even faster (around 50ms on my system). I do, however, foresee some problems in combination with faulty XML or '<' characters in texts. This could be solved by adding some safety checks, but this probably slows it down a bit. I will mark this as the answer, thanks again! :)

Answer (score 3):

C++11 regex replace is indeed rather slow, as of yet, at least. PCRE performs much better in terms of pattern matching speed, however, PCRECPP provides very limited means for regular expression based substitution, citing the man page:

> You can replace the first match of "pattern" in "str" with "rewrite".
>   Within "rewrite", backslash-escaped digits (\1 to \9) can be used to
>   insert text matching corresponding parenthesized group from the
>   pattern. \0 in "rewrite" refers to the entire matching text.

This is really poor, compared to Perl's 's' command. That is why I wrote my own C++ wrapper around PCRE that handles regular expression based substitution in a fashion that is close to Perl's 's', and also supports 16- and 32-bit character strings: [PCRSCPP](https://github.com/alllexx88/pcrscpp):

> #### Command string syntax
>
> Command syntax follows Perl `s/pattern/substitute/[options]`
>   convention. Any character (except the backslash `\`) can be used as a
>   delimiter, not just `/`, but make sure that delimiter is escaped with
>   a backslash (`\`) if used in `pattern`, `substitute` or `options`
>   substrings, e.g.:
>
> - `s/\\/\//g` to replace all backslashes with forward ones
>
> Remember to double backslashes in C++ code, unless using raw string
>   literal (see [string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)):
>
> `pcrscpp::replace rx("s/\\\\/\\//g");`
>
> #### Pattern string syntax
>
> Pattern string is passed directly to `pcre*_compile`, and thus has to
>   follow PCRE syntax as described in [PCRE documentation](http://pcre.org/pcre.txt).
>
> #### Substitute string syntax
>
> Substitute string backreferencing syntax is similar to Perl's:
>
> - `$1` ... `$n`: nth capturing subpattern matched.
> - `$&` and `$0`: the whole match
> - `${label}`   : labled subpattern matched. `label` is up to 32 alphanumerical +
>                    underscore characters (`'A'-'Z'`,`'a'-'z'`,`'0'-'9'`,`'_'`),
>                    first character must be alphabetical
> - `` $` `` and `$'` (backtick and tick) refer to the areas of the subject before
>                      and after the match, respectively. As in Perl, the unmodified
>                      subject is used, even if a global substitution previously matched.
>
> Also, following escape sequences get recognized:
>
> - `\n`: newline
> - `\r`: carriage return
> - `\t`: horizontal tab
> - `\f`: form feed
> - `\b`: backspace
> - `\a`: alarm, bell
> - `\e`: escape
> - `\0`: binary zero
>
> Any other escape sequence `\<char>`, is interpreted as `<char>`,
>   meaning that you have to escape backslashes too
>
> #### Options string syntax
>
> In Perl-like manner, options string is a sequence of allowed modifier
>   letters. PCRSCPP recognizes following modifiers:
>
> 1. Perl-compatible flags
>
>    - `g`: global replace, not just the first match
>    - `i`: case insensitive match
>        (PCRE_CASELESS)
>    - `m`: multi-line mode: `^` and `$` additionally match positions
>         after and before newlines, respectively
>         (PCRE_MULTILINE)
>    - `s`: let the scope of the `.` metacharacter include newlines
>         (treat newlines as ordinary characters)
>         (PCRE_DOTALL)
>    - `x`: allow extended regular expression syntax,
>         enabling whitespace and comments in complex patterns
>         (PCRE_EXTENDED)
> 2. PHP-compatible flags
>
>    - `A`: "anchor" pattern: look only for "anchored" matches: ones that
>         start with zero offset. In single-line mode is identical to
>         prefixing all pattern alternative branches with `^`
>         (PCRE_ANCHORED)
>    - `D`: treat dollar `$` as subject end assertion only, overriding the default:
>         end, or immediately before a newline at the end.
>         Ignored in multi-line mode
>         (PCRE_DOLLAR_ENDONLY)
>    - `U`: invert `*` and `+` greediness logic: make ungreedy by default,
>         `?` switches back to greedy. `(?U)` and `(?-U)` in-pattern switches
>         remain unaffected
>         (PCRE_UNGREEDY)
>    - `u`: Unicode mode. Treat pattern and subject as UTF8/UTF16/UTF32 string.
>         Unlike in PHP, also affects newlines, `\R`, `\d`, `\w`, etc. matching
>         ((PCRE_UTF8/PCRE_UTF16/PCRE_UTF32) | PCRE_NEWLINE_ANY
>          | PCRE_BSR_UNICODE | PCRE_UCP)
> 3. PCRSCPP own flags:
>
>    - `N`: skip empty matches
>         (PCRE_NOTEMPTY)
>    - `T`: treat substitute as a trivial string, i.e., make no backreference
>         and escape sequences interpretation
>    - `n`: discard non-matching portions of the string to replace
>         Note: PCRSCPP does *not* automatically add newlines,
>         the replacement result is plain concatenation of matches,
>         be specifically aware of this in multiline mode

I wrote a simple speed test code, which stores a 10x copy of file "move.sh" and tests regex performance on resulting string:

```
#include <pcrscpp.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <regex>

#include <chrono>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const std::string file_name("move.sh");
    pcrscpp::replace pcrscpp_rx(R"del(s/(?:^|\n)mv[ \t]+(?:-f)?[ \t]+"([^\n]+)"[ \t]+"([^\n]+)"(?:$|\n)/$1\n$2\n/Dgn)del");
    std::regex std_rx          (R"del((?:^|\n)mv[ \t]+(?:-f)?[ \t]+"([^\n]+)"[ \t]+"([^\n]+)"(?:$|\n))del");

    std::ifstream file (file_name);
    if (!file.is_open ()) {
        std::cerr << "Unable to open file " << file_name << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    std::string buffer;
    {
        file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
        size_t size = file.tellg();
        file.seekg(0);
        if (size > 0) {
            buffer.resize(size);
            file.read(&buffer[0], size);
            buffer.resize(size - 1); // strip '\0'
        }
    }
    file.close();
    std::string bigstring;
    bigstring.reserve(10*buffer.size());
    for (std::string::size_type i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        bigstring.append(buffer);

    int n = 10;

    std::cout << "Running tests " << n << " times: be patient..." << std::endl;

    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::duration std_regex_duration, pcrscpp_duration;
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t1, t2;
    std::string result1, result2;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        // clear result
        std::string().swap(result1);
        t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        result1 = std::regex_replace (bigstring, std_rx, "$1\\n$2", std::regex_constants::format_no_copy);
        t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        std_regex_duration = (std_regex_duration*i + (t2 - t1)) / (i + 1);

        // clear result
        std::string().swap(result2);

        t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        result2 = pcrscpp_rx.replace_copy (bigstring);
        t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        pcrscpp_duration = (pcrscpp_duration*i + (t2 - t1)) / (i + 1);
    }
    std::cout << "Time taken by std::regex_replace: "
              << std_regex_duration.count()
              << " ms" << std::endl
              << "Result size: " << result1.size() << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Time taken by pcrscpp::replace: "
              << pcrscpp_duration.count()
              << " ms" << std::endl
              << "Result size: " << result2.size() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

(note that `std` and `pcrscpp` regular expressions do the same here, the trailing newline in expression for `pcrscpp` is due to `std::regex_replace` not stripping newlines despite `std::regex_constants::format_no_copy`)

and launched it on a large (20.9 MB) shell move script:

```
Running tests 10 times: be patient...
Time taken by std::regex_replace: 12090771487 ms
Result size: 101087330
Time taken by pcrscpp::replace: 5910315642 ms
Result size: 101087330
```

As you can see, PCRSCPP is more than 2x faster. And I expect this gap to grow with pattern complexity increase, since PCRE deals with complicated patterns much better. I originally wrote a wrapper for myself, but I think it can be useful for others too.

Regards,
Alex