# how to remove a substring of unknown length from a string - C++

Tags: c++, string, sed, stdstring

I have a string (URL) which I know part of, but not all of it. Some of the string I want to remove, but the string can vary in length, so I can't use the `erase()` function from `<string>`.

An example URL I may work with:
`https://github.com/username/repo-name`

After parsing, I would like to be left with just `repo-name`

I know I can do this easily in shell with the `sed` command:

```sh
 echo "https://github.com/username/repo-name" | sed 's/.*\///'
```

Ideally, I would like something I could turn into a function, so I could do something like:

```
string substring = sed("s/.*\///",var);
```

Please keep in mind that I do **not** know the full string to be removed. In the case of the URL I showed, I want everything before, and including the final '/', but, the username is subject to change. so from what I understand I can't use things such as `erase()` or `rfind()`.

**EDIT**

All URLs I am parsing are GitHub URLs, so they will all be similar to this, another part of the program this will go in will ensure they all follow this same syntax.

Comment: Open your C++ book to the chapter that explains what things you can do with `std::string`, and read the description of what the `rfind` method does.

Comment: I don't have a C++ book, but I will look it up. Thanks.

Comment: [tag:c++] and [tag:sed] are an odd pair of tags.

Comment: You can take a look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42172674/performing-a-regex-search-and-replace-on-a-stdstring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `rfind` to get the location of the last slash then `substr` to return the right side of the string. Since `substr`'s second argument defaults to "the end of the string" you only need to provide the beginning position:

```
#include <string>

std::string GetURLFilePath(const std::string& url) {
    auto last_slash_location = url.rfind('/');
    if(last_slash_location == std::string::npos || last_slash_location + 1 >= url.size()) {
        return "";
    }
    return url.substr(last_slash_location + 1);
}
```

You didn't really say if you are expecting parameters (`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk`) so this will obviously not be exactly what you want if those exist in the string, but it'll get you to the right track.

Comment: That worked wonders! Thank you!